# Dart map of 2 lists to sort

Tags: list, dart, mapping

I have 2 lists:
distancestring[1][3], with the following values:

```
distancestring[0][0]=3.4
distancestring[0][1]=2
distancestring[0][2]=1.1
distancestring[1][0]=5
distancestring[1][1]=4.2
```

and imagestring[1][3], with the following values:

```
imagestring[0][0]="ccc"
imagestring[0][1]="aaa"
imagestring[0][2]="ddd"
imagestring[1][0]="bbb"
imagestring[1][1]="eee"
```

I would like to have a third list "result" with values of imagestring according to distancestring order.
Result should have items:

```
result[0][0]="ddd"
result[0][1]="aaa"
result[0][2]="ccc"
result[1][0]="eee"
result[1][1]="bbb"
```

Hope I made my self clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure the following can be done more efficient but here is my suggestion on how it can be done.

Please note that it is important that `distancestring` and `imagestring` does have the same structure of elements like your example.

```
void main() {
  final distancestring = [
    [3.4, 2, 1.1],
    [5, 4.2]
  ];

  final imagestring = [
    ['ccc', 'aaa', 'ddd'],
    ['bbb', 'eee']
  ];

  print(distancestring); // [[3.4, 2, 1.1], [5, 4.2]]
  print(imagestring); // [[ccc, aaa, ddd], [bbb, eee]]
  print(sort(
      distancestring,
      imagestring,
      (dynamic d1, dynamic d2) =>
          d1.compareTo(d2) as int)); // [[ddd, aaa, ccc], [eee, bbb]]
}

class Pair<A, B> {
  final A a;
  final B b;

  const Pair(this.a, this.b);
}

List<List<B>> sort<A, B>(List<List<A>> distancestring,
    List<List<B>> imagestring, int Function(A, A) compare) {
  final temp = <Pair<A, B>>[];

  for (var i = 0; i < distancestring.length; i++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < distancestring[i].length; k++) {
      temp.add(Pair(distancestring[i][k], imagestring[i][k]));
    }
  }

  temp.sort((e1, e2) => compare(e1.a, e2.a));

  var count = 0;
  final result = <List<B>>[];

  for (var i = 0; i < distancestring.length; i++) {
    final list = <B>[];

    for (var k = 0; k < distancestring[i].length; k++) {
      list.add(temp[count++].b);
    }

    result.add(list);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @julemand101! Only problem is I have a dynamic imagestring and distancestring. They are set later. So code give:
Error: Inferred type argument 'Comparable<dynamic>' doesn't conform to the bound 'Comparable<A>' of the type variable 'A' on 'sort'.
Any solution for this?

Comment: I have updated my example so the compare method can be given as argument to the sort method which removes the requirement of A to be Comparable. But then it is up to you to make sure the compare method works for you input. :)

Comment: Good to hear. I have updated the code again with a performance improvement. Instead of removing elements from the `temp` list (and shifting the elements each time) I instead just use a counter to know which element I should add next.